# Facebook security check is broken and sends 5 digit code instead of 6

Tags: facebook, login

As the title suggests the security check has been sending a 5 digit code to my phone instead of a 6 digit one, which is not accepted. This has rendered my account unable to log in so I can't contact Facebook. Its been like this for months, I was hoping they would fix it but if no-one can tell them about it then they probably don't even know.

Without logging in I can't post in the help section or even send a message about the fault. Creating a fake profile doesn't work either as they close it down the moment I speak of another account. There is no way to pass the security check as even if I prove my identity by changing the password the same screen comes up straight after, also it does this on my phone, tablet and laptop so its not a devise problem.

So 2 related questions:

1. Is there a way to contact Facebook without logging in?
2. Has anyone else experienced this problem and solved it?

I would like to have my account back before Christmas as a lot of people I know use it to make arrangements, although it seems like that may be unlikely.

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have my account back so I'm adding this in case anyone else has a faulty security check screen like this

The only way I found to bypass the security check was to deliberately disable the account by answering the security check incorrectly (repeatedly). Once the account is disabled you can request it be reopened by sending a photo of your ID. The account has to be disabled before you can do this using the link in the help section

This is a bit of an extreme option, but if the security screen wont let you pass even though you answer the security questions correctly, then this is a way to unlock the account

Comment: For anyone having this issue when trying to setup a **Developer Account** - I was able to fix this by enabling 2fa from my normal facebook settings. Once I did this (and thankfully a different 6digit code was sent) the "phone verification" step from setting up the dev account was skipped (after clearing cookies / using incognito)

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely to happen as Today I checked and its working.

Latest Android devices having the below problem:

The problem may be in your phone smart SMS services. Many a time I need to look into the original text of SMS to get the code as my android SMS shows me a card type Message which looks fine but may show wrong code.

So, I suggest you to don't just look the message rather open the SMS in plain text format (sometimes "original text"). you can find a button on the SMS to see its original text.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: My phone does not allow for a text to be viewed in plain text, so I cant do that. The code has now expired and the resend button doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

This happened to a coworker, for him it worked putting a zero after the five digits he received in a text message.

Hopefully this works for someone else too!